# How to resample dataframe with a linear interpolation by hour

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

So, this has been somewhat answered, except that it is a little more challenging with the hour mark and I have been running into a problem trying to return the datetime. So, basically I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                     elev  Dewpoint Temp
time                                      
2014-06-28 12:13:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 12:28:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 12:43:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 12:58:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 13:13:33  1125.0       6.666667
2014-06-28 13:28:33  1125.0       6.666667
2014-06-28 13:43:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 13:58:33  1125.0       7.222222
2014-06-28 14:13:33  1125.0       6.666667
...
2014-08-31 11:02:14  1125.0      10.555556
2014-08-31 11:17:13  1125.0      11.111111
2014-08-31 11:17:14  1125.0      10.555556
2014-08-31 11:32:13  1125.0      10.555556
2014-08-31 11:47:13  1125.0      10.000000
2014-08-31 11:47:14  1125.0      10.000000
```

And I want this to be in hour increments, on the hour so that I can compare it to some theoretical data that only measures data by the hour.

I have tried to use the following code to solve my dilemma:

```
dftemp01=df00.resample(rule='1H',closed='left').last().reset_index().fillna(method='ffill')
dftemp02=df00.resample(rule='1H',closed='left').first().reset_index().fillna(method='ffill')
dt0=dftemp01.datetime-dftemp02.datetime
df00['Observed']=dftemp01+dt0*dftemp02
```

Where df00 is the dataframe above. I am dropping the rest of the dataframe in a line later on, which works fine. However, I run into two issues.

1) I don't think this is doing what I want. What I'd like specifically is for instance the hour 13:00, take point at 12:58, then move forward 2 minutes linearly, along the line determined by the next point subtracted by the point prior, divided by the time elapse between the two.

2) I am not getting anything back from the `dftemp01.datetime`. I have tried `dftemp01.date_time` and other iterations, as well as `dftemp01.index.to_pydatetime()`. These have not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this after some attempts. This isn't the most beautiful coding, but it does work to solve sampling issues regardless of the sampling times to make sampling reflect (to the best of the knowledge given) what your data should look like:

```
lfile00=path0+dewpointstring+filetype0
df00=xselect(lfile00,v00,starttime,endtime)
df00[v00]=((df00[v00]-32.)*5./9.)
dsll=xr.open_dataset(lfile00)
dftemp0=df00[v00].resample('S').mean()
dftemp0=dftemp0.interpolate()
df00=df00.resample('H').mean()
df00['Observed']=dftemp0.resample('H').mean()
df00=df00.drop(['elev',v00],1)
```

Be warned; however, that if your dataframes are huge, (Like more than a few months) the interpolating and resampling by 1 second intervals may end up giving you some headaches with the data sizes. I am not sure how to work around this. Thankfully, my data does not need it. If anyone is interested in how to work around it, I can try to come up with a way within the next few weeks.